# Reading particular column from a table in a text file using C

Tags: arrays, c

I have a text file with a large matrix (56*10000). But here is a sample.

```
A  B  C  D
1  3  4  5
3  5  6  10
2  2  6  11
3  2  3  38
3  3  1  19
```

I have a code which can read the file and also print it. I have two problems.

1. I can't seem to find a way to print a particular column. For example in MATLAB, if we want to print the second column we indicate it like [:,2].
2. Is there way where I can access the column by a particular name. For example, since these columns are named A B C D, if I want to print the second column, I just have to say, `if case in B, print (B)` and it has to print,

```
3
5
2
2
3
```

Here is the code that I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  int M = 5, N = 4;
  char filter[1024] ;

  double *Z_BS = (double *)malloc(M * N * sizeof(double));
  
  fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    {
      exit(1);
    }
  
  fgets(filter,1024,fp);
  
  for (int rows = 0; rows < M; rows++)
    {
      for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++)
    {
      fscanf(fp, "%lf", Z_BS);
      printf("%lf\t", *Z_BS);  
    }
      printf("\n");
      if (feof(fp))
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that too. That is in fact my alternate code. But how do you print an entire column. I know I can use for loop. But if I have to print 20 random columns from 56 columns then I think this method becomes cumbersome. @user3121023

Answer (score 1):

In `C` there is no way like matlab, but with the help of below idea you can generate the required offset

`offset = row_size*i + column_number`

lets say there are five 5 rows and 5 columns and you want to access 3 column.

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

```
when i = 0,  5*0+3 = 3
when i = 1,  5*1+3 = 8
when i = 2,  5*2+3 = 13
when i = 3,  5*3+3 = 18
when i = 4,  5*4+3 = 23
```

NOTE: check for EOF always or the `offset` is valid before using, you should not access anything beyond the file.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated, but if you just want to print the values, there's no need to allocate memory.
Using a local variable is enough

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < M; rows++) {
    for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++) {
        double Z_BS;
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &Z_BS);
        printf("%lf\t", Z_BS);  
    }

    printf("\n");
    if (feof(fp)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

---

To print just one column, you can simply use the `col` variable, say print the second column

```
for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++) {
    double Z_BS;
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", &Z_BS);
    if (cols == 1)
        printf("%lf\t", Z_BS);  
}
```

It says `cols == 1`, because the loop starts at `0` (first column = 0, second column = 1, ...).

---

To print by column name, don't skip the first row, but compare the name, e.g.

```
char colname[] = "B";
int colnum;

// Scan header row
for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++) {
    char current[51];
    fscanf(fp, "%.50s", current);
    if (strcmp(current, colname) == 0) {
        colnum = cols;
        break;
    }
}
```

and later while printing

```
if (cols == colnum)
    printf("%lf\t", Z_BS);
```

Comment: This is perfect. But instead of using `if(cols == 1)`, how can I call it by a specific name. For ex: as i said earlier if I have to print the second column it should take the column name. So the code should be `if (cols == B)`, it should print the second column. Is there a way I can do that? @Olaf Dietsche

Comment: This is more involved, because you must lookup the column names from the first row, and then save the column number for later comparison.